# Plotting scatter points with matplotlib from a CSV file question

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have extracted some data from a website into a CSV file and I need to plot a scatterplot in matplotlib from that CSV file. I only need column 2 and 3 data from the CSV file.

I'm trying to use a for loop to gather CSV data into a list and then use that to plot the scatterplot but I'm getting a "ValueError: x and y must be the same size" error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open(cache_path + distance_csv) as csv_file:
reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

for column in reader:
    city_distance = [x[1] for x in csv.reader(csv_file)]
    crime_rate = [x[2] for x in csv.reader(csv_file)]

    plt.scatter(city_distance, crime_rate)
    plt.show()
```

Both columns 2 and 3 in my CSV file are the same length - 83 cells yet I am getting a ValueError. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please provide a link to the data file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some bugs in your code, I can't know which of them is causing your behaviour but after you fix them all you could progress:

1. First, look how you read the columns. Notice that you iterate over *column in reader* but never use *column* (you create two new csv.readers in every iteration in the for loop). Look at a possible solution afterwards in this answer.
2. Regarding to that, you're reading *csv_file* outside the scope of the 'with' statement so the file would be already closed. If you'll use the for loop and *column* you won't have to fix this issue anyway.
3. You're plotting in every iteration (thus you'll create 83 plots and I guess you don't want that).

So a possible solution would be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open(cache_path + distance_csv) as csv_file:
  reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
city_distance, crime_rate  = [], []
for column in reader:
  city_distance.append(float(column[1]))
  crime_rate.append(float(column[2]))
plt.scatter(city_distance, crime_rate)
plt.show()
```

For future, I'll recommend that you try to verify that `len(city_distance)==len(crime_rate)`. 
I mean, check your data not in the csv but rather in the code, after reading the values and right before the error - to have the most usable information to proceed.